# Handling checkboxes when selected

Tags: java

If I have a check box for example

```
Jcheckbox cb = new Jcheckbox("cappuccino");
JLabel lbl = new JLabel("8000");
JTextfield txt = new JTextfield();
```

When I select **cappuccino** I want the price label **8000** to be copied to textfield txt, some one to help me on this but am using netbeans palettes.

```
The checkbox is declared as 
private javax.swing.JCheckbox Cb1;
*//handler method is *
private void Cb1ItemStateChanged(javax.awt.event.ItemListener evt) {
```

//to do code here
}

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the doc and use the methods...

```
JCheckBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
      public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
         //here your code
      }
    });
```

and

```
JTextfield.setText("put your text here");
```

and

```
String xxx =  JLabel.getText()
```

Comment: I just tried that but it failed remember am using private abstract  methods

Comment: could you please post the hole code where you are using that snippet?

Comment: Unfortunately am using a phone

Comment: no problem... add a comment as soon as you update the question so I can check it out....

Comment: Update is submitted

Comment: Update is submitted